# Replace html of a div after anchor tag?

Tags: jquery

This is a quick example not my actual code. Onclick of the div `button`, how do i replace the html after the anchor tag or parent div `title`?  The jQuery code here replaces everything in the div `title` i only want to replace what is after the anchor tag.

script

```
$(function() {

    $('.button').live('click',function() {
    var info = $(this).next('.information').html();
    $(this).next('.title').html(info);
    });
});
```

html

```
<div class='container'> 
    <div class='button'>Click Me</div>
    <div class='information' style='display:none;'>information</div>
    <div class='title'><a href='http://www.example.com/' class='link'></a>title</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap that in a `span`

```
<div class='title'><a href='http://www.example.com/' class='link'></a><span>title</span></div>
```

and target that with

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').live('click',function() {
      var self = $(this);
      var info = self.nextAll('.information').html();
      self.nextAll('.title').find('span').html(info);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I changed and I think this jsFiddle is close to what you need - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/LHPT2/

1) The `$title` should probably be within the anchor tag

2) The `information` div should be before the button since you're using `.prev()`

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.button').live('click', function() {
        var info = $(this).prev('.information').html();
        $(this).next('.title').children('a').text(info);
    });
});

</script>
<?php

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 

$id = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$information = $row['information'];

echo "<div class='container'> 
<div class='information' style='display:none;'>$information</div>
<div class='button'>Click Me</div>
<div class='title'><a href='http://www.example.com/' class='link'>$title</a></div>
</div>";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of working with `prev()` and `next()`, try to work with `siblings()`

```
$('.button').live('click',function() {

var info = $(this).siblings('.information').html();

$(this).siblings('.title').html(info);

});
```

Comment: I only want to replace the html after the anchor tag, how do i do that?